# Different rich text tags for different new line breakers(\r, \n, \r\n)

Tags: winforms, newline, richtextbox, richtext

I'm trying to edit code (C++/C#/Java) in a RichTextBox of a winfrom application.
Since there are different new line breakers in different platform, I'm using these code to encode the rich text:

```
            value = value
                .Replace("\r\n", "\\par ")
                .Replace("\r", "\\par ")
                .Replace("\n", "\\par ");
```

All the 3 types of newline breakers are displayed fine. But then I noticed that, since \r\n(2 chars in file content) has been encoded as \par (1 char in RichTextBox.Text), the index of a certain text differs. Thus RichTextBox.Select(index, length) will select text in the wrong position, if the position was calculated from the raw file content. For each more line, the difference of index increases 1.

I'm thinking if there is anything like "\\return\\par", which is counted as 2 chars but displayed as 1 newline breaker; and in RichTextBox.Text(it will be saved as the file content), it is decoded back as "\r\n".

And if not, is there any other way to align index of file content and RichTextBox.Text? Thanks.

BTW I have a dirty way to walk around: RichTextBox.Select(index - lineNo, length). But it's really ugly.

Comment: RichTextBox only uses `\n` as line separator. All `\r` (if present in the source text) are automatically removed.

Comment: @Jimi So RichTextBox.Text is always shorter than the original content of the file when \r\n is used as new line breaker?

Comment: Yep. Line breaks should be excluded if you need to *synchronize* the source. Consider just the lines' content. The Control (TextBoxBase, actually) provides means to determine the line based on a char position and the starting char of that line (among other things).

Comment: @Jimi Great! Fortunately, I do have the line numbers. Just thought using index is much more easier than line no. Now it's :             Select(GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(startLineNo - 1), 
                GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(endLineNo - 1) + Lines[endLineNo - 1].Length); //-1: LineNo starts with 1 rather than 0.
And it works fine, thanks! You can answer my question with a formal answer, and I will mark it as the right one.